# SocketIO empty FormData received at Flask backend

Tags: reactjs, flask, events, socket.io, form-data

I'm trying to send some form values including file via SocketIO

```
    const handleSubmit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('num1', numbers.num1);
    formData.append('num2', numbers.num2);
    formData.append('file', file);

    socket.emit('submit', {payload: formData});
};
```

In `console.log()` I see

`numbers.num1, numbers.num2, file:  1 1  File { name: "data.zip", lastModified: 1691230842633, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1196056, type: "application/x-zip-compressed" }`

Event on backend receives

`{'payload': {}}`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
CORS(app)

socketio.init_app(
app,
cors_allowed_origins="*",
logger=True,
engineio_logger=True)


@socketio.on('submit')
def handle_submit(data):
...


if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Why the payload missing at the event handler?

**UPD:**

In Chrome I receive just `{}`, in Firefox `{'payload': {}}`

**UPD2:**
The reason why the data is empty is FormData on FE which is empty after `append()`. What's causing such behavior?

Comment: Using a FormData object doesn't really make sense here since you don't want to send a form.
To upload a file, check out [this tutorial](https://socket.io/how-to/upload-a-file). A nested structure with additional data and information about the file is also possible.

Comment: @Detlef If I need to send file and several number values, should I emit 2 separate event to sent values in json and file as socket.emit("upload", files[0).
I use the FormData to pass them together

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple data, including a file, via the socket you can use a nested structure.

The following example shows you a possible variant, where `file`, as in the [tutorial](https://socket.io/how-to/upload-a-file) mentioned above, corresponds to a file that was taken as the first element from a FileList of an input element.

```js
socket.emit('submit', 
    { 
        num1: numbers.num1, 
        num2: numbers.num2, 
        file: { 
            name: file.name, 
            type: file.type, 
            size: file.size, 
            data: file 
        }
    }
);
```

On the server side you get a dictionary that contains the file's data as bytes.